# Show me that exists a sequence $(a_n)$ such that $(a_n)$ has a subsequence converging for each real number

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I'm a braziliam undergraduate student of mathematics. I don't know the nomenclature for this in english, but in portuguese if a sequence $(a_n)$ has a subsequence $(a^{'}_n)$ with $\lim (a^{'}_n) = L$, then $L$ is a "ponto de aderência" (I did put this setence in google translate and I saw "grip point")

My try: We can't do this. Because a sequence is a one-to-one function from the natural numbers to real numbers. "We don't have enough points" to make subsequences for all real numbers.

I don't have the answer. But some of my friends told me that the answer is Yes.

Comment: Your friend is right, you can find an example in the link